# Catalog from previous puppet run did not got removed automatically. Why?

Tags: centos, puppet

I did a puppet run from command line together on  centos and ubuntu nodes which did not go well and I aborted it by pressing control-c on the agents.

I then changed the manifests on the server, and again did the puppet run. This time the manifest was right, so it ran properly on the ubuntu node, but on the centos node, puppet agent tried to apply the old manifests.

ON inquiring the /var/lib/puppet/client_data/ directory on centos nodes, I found the old catalog to be still present. But they were not in the ubuntu nodes. After deleting the old catalog from the centos nodes my puppet run ran fine.

I have aborted the puppet run from command line many times, but this happened for the first time.

Just want to know in which cases does the catalogs of previous puppet run does not gets removed automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Won't get removed if the master throws an error compiling the config.  The agent falls back to applying the last config it received.

Watch the logs on the master to ensure the CentOS box is getting a good config sent to it.